# Creating a conditional statement based on accessories in tableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am trying to create a conditional statement that does things based on if a tableView has any checkmark accessories.

Currently, I have the following code that checks to see if records are selected, but I would instead like to check if checkmark accessories exist in any rows in the tableView, can something like this be verified?

**Code to see if rows are selected:**

```
if structure.isEmpty || 
(tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows != nil && 
!tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows!.isEmpty) {

//Do this...

} else {

//Do this...

}
```

`structure` is defined as `var structure = [JSONStructure]()`

JSONStructure is the structure of the JSON data that is populating the tableView.

Comment: The most efficient and reliable way is to put the `selected` information into the `JSONStructure` data model.

Comment: Vadian, can you please elaborate more on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you adding an array which keeps track of the rows with checkmark accessories, so when you add a checkmark you add the indexPath of that row to the array as well, and the same when you remove the checkmark

```
let checkedCells = [IndexPath]()
```

Now you can add your statement like this

```
if structure.isEmpty || !checkedCells.isEmpty {

    //Do this...

} else {

    //Do this...

}
```